Find the values of $m$ and $n$ for which $\int_{0}^{1} x^n\exp{(-mx)}dx$ converges.
I need to find the values of $m$ and $n$, so that the following integral converges:
$$\int_{0}^{1} x^n\exp{(-mx)}dx$$
My attempt:Case-1:If $n\ge0$ then the given integral is proper integral irrespective of $m$ and hence convergent.Case-2:If $n<0$ then $0$ is the point of infinite discontinuity,so it will become an improper integral.Now i want to use comparison test for convergence of this integral.In a text book it is given that:In $[0,1]$, $x^n\exp(-mx)\le kx^n$,for some $k>1$ and $\forall m$.I am unable to verify this inequality and also i do not know other way to solve this problem.
Kindly help me.

$m$ any, $n>-1$

What is the maximal value of $e^{-m x}$ in $[0, 1]$ ? Also what is its minimal value?

@Gribouillis Sir,if $m<0$ then its minimal and mximal values on [0,1] are $1$ and $exp(-m)$ respectively.If if $m> 0$ then its minimal and mximal values on [0,1] are $exp(-m)$ and $1$ respectively.

@BobDobbs Can you give a hint?

@Gribouillis in case m<0 the inequality fails.

Hint:
$$c_1\int_0^1x^ndx\leq\int_0^1x^ne^{-mx}dx\leq c_2\int_0^1x^ndx$$
where $c_1=\min_{x\in[0,1]} e^{-mx}$ and $c_2=\max_{x\in[0,1]} e^{-mx}.$

excellent hint!!

thank you so much sir.

I thank you more!!! It is maybe my last answer in MSE.

Why last??You can help more.

@Mathew İ did 2 more. But İ am in a big war against a big enemy in my country and university. Pride war. İ have no life or soul safety.
